# VBA define property in a variable

Tags: vba, excel, properties

I am new to the forum, and also new to VBA (only started learning it a week ago).

Is it possible to define a property in a variable? I have a line that looks kind of like this:

```
Cells(i, j).Formula = "=" & .Cells(i, j).Address(External:=True, RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
```

I have to write several cells, so I end up having many of these lines; if possible, I would like to do something like:

```
dim prop as string

prop = "Address(External:=True, RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)"

Cells(i, j).Formula = "=" & .Cells(i, j).prop
```

Can something like this be done?

Comment: No, you can't do that in VBA.  If you want to cut down on repetitive code then you could write a small Sub to create the link between the two cells.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer is "no", but I'm not sure enough to make that an actual answer. The real question is why you'd want to do something like this? In my opinion it would make the code much harder to read and as for creating multiple lines with very similar syntax copy-paste is your friend there. If the lines are VERY similar consider using a loop.

Comment: Not really - CallByName would be the closest equivalent. You could also just write a function that returns that information for a Range object passed as an argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
Function MyProp(ByVal r as Range) as String
    MyProp = r.Address(External:=True, RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
End Function


...
Cells(i,j).Formula = "="& MyProp( Cells(i,j) )
```

This of course makes a cell reference itself, which is generally a bad idea and may lead to circular references. Best if you describe more on what you are trying to do in order to get better answers.

Comment: Perfect! This is along the lines I was thinking. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments this cannot be done in the way you describe.  There are two alternatives:

1. Write a Private Function that you call with your input and expected output (more complicated)
2. Write a loop with the code only appearing once. (less code)

To write a loop for all cells from A1 to Last used row, last used column:

```
Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long

LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For i = 1 To LastRow
    For j = 1 to LastCol
        `Do your stuff here
    Next j
Next i
```

Edit:
I'm going to assume you need to invest in the `Range.Offset()` method [found here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840060%28v=office.15%29.aspx) because right now, you are setting the cell's formula as equal to itself...

Comment: Thanks! I tried the private function, but didn't end up making the code more elegant; by references are from different sheets, so if I have a function than I also have to pass the sheet reference, which was just as long as messy.